# Mysql performances: serialize vs columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's say that I have array like the one I posted below and that I need to store it in my MySQL database:

```
Array(
    "Weight" => "10",
    "Height" => "17",
    "Usage" => "35"
);
```

Preamble:

- I will **never** update these values
- I will **never** perform a query based on these values

Long story short I only need to **store** and **display** this array as it is. Actually I need to use these values to generate graphs. Now I see 2 possible options.

Option 1: even if I will never use a WHERE, ORDER BY, HAVING (...) condition on these values, I store each value separately in a dedicated column (weight, height, usage).

Option 2: I create a single column (stats) where I store a serialized version of the array then, in order generate my graphs, I unserialize each row before using it.

The question is: what's the best approach to store this array in terms of effectiveness and performaces?

In my opinion the second approach is the best but let's say that there are many rows and elements involved in the process. I don't understand if it's faster and ligher to unserialize an array made by 20 elements for 100 rows with PHP or to read plain values stored in 20 columns considering that I need to save lot of them very frequently and simultaneously.

Comment: The simple fact that you wouldn't need to unserialize to create your graphs if you were using separate columns should be enough to justify option #1

Comment: Why even store it in the database? The whole point of storing stuff in a database is that you can execute queries on/with it. Otherwise you're better off setting the values in a constant in your code.

Comment: i would always chose option 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will never update these values
>
> I will never perform a query based on these values

The second you finalise your code having stored them as serialised values, you'll be asked to perform a query to update anything with a weight above ten.

Just store them in their own columns - not only will this future-proof the code, but it is easier to work with and will take up less drive space in the long run.

Comment: I see your point. For sure option 1 is better when we're talking about displaying data but what about the storing part? Let me explain. I'll do many more INSERT queries than SELECT ones. In fact I need select and display these values only when clients want to see graphs but obviously they will not spend a lifetime looking at graphs. On the other and I continuously need to save new values during my automated checks very frequenly. In conclusion it would be an INSERT INTO 20 columns against an INSERT INTO a single column with a serialize(data). That said, do you still recommend option 1?

Comment: I would. SQL is designed for inserts and reads like this- but it is not designed for serialized data, as is evident by the gross lack of support for it. Maybe use the new MySQL (5.7+) JSON functionality? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html Otherwise, go with rows and relational data.

Comment: Thank you all guys. Today I learned something new. Let's go with columns and stop overthinking.